# Implement search like the People search

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

**Is there an implementation/example of the Windows Phone native search in the People hup ?** (shows a ListBox and typing in the SearchBox will filter the people in the list, and highlighting the matching texts). I was especially looking for a modification of the Windows Phone Toolkit AutocompleteBox.

If nothing exists already, **what would I need to do to mix the Toolkit LongListSelector with AutoCompleteBox** (replacing the autocomplete popup with a filtering of a list) **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen anything, because it's so easy to implement. As for implementing it with the LongListSelector and a AutoCompleteBox, you should simply use either a `CollectionViewSource` or having a *original*, and *filtered*, data source, where the active displays the filtered items.

Comment: Jorgensen - Ahh.. 404 on those files.

Comment: For some reason CollectionViewSource doesn't work as an LongListSelector itemssource on the Windows Phone 8.