# Implementing native search function on listbox in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, search, listbox

I currently have a listbox that gets populated and wanted to know how to easily incorporate the native windows search function that one sees in the 'people' app for example..

There is [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373294/implement-search-like-the-people-search) that deals with the same issue but the example that the accepted answer points to no longer exists it seems.

I would like to have the search function pop-up on a clickHandler.. naturally.
Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: @@Relborg Am also trying to implement same search functionality :) if u implement this please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you have to implement something custom in this case.

If you just want to filter the items by a first letter then you can use LongListSelector as explained here http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/LongListSelector-walkthrough

If you want to have a textbox based search-filter then you have execute a search command on every  TextChanged event within the textbox(input area for search criteria). Search command will iterate though the items and filter those which correspond to the entered criteria.